# Add image to menu/sitemap element in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-4.7

I am using TYPO3 4.7 (Upgrading is not an option). Can I customize the Menu/Sitemap element to include the first image on each linked page?

So In this case I'd be using:

```
tt_content.menu.20.1.1.NO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you really should update the site as there are **a lot security issues** which can do harm to your/your customer's website.

Back to your question: Of course you can render any content inside a menu as well!

```
lib.menu = HMENU
lib.menu {
    wrap = <ul>|</ul>
    1 = TMENU
    1.NO {
        wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
        after.cObject = CONTENT
        after.cObject {
            table = tt_content
            select {
                pidInList.field = uid
            }
            renderObj = COA
            renderObj {
                10 = TEXT
                10.field = header
                10.htmlSpecialChars = 1

                20 = TEXT
                20 {
                    field = image
                    split {
                        token = ,
                        cObjNum = 1
                        1 {
                            10 = IMAGE
                            10 {
                                file {
                                    import=uploads/pics/
                                    import.current = 1
                                    width = 170
                                    height = 100
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

tt_content.menu.20.1.1.NO < lib.menu.1.NO
```

To be honest: the part with the image is untested as I don't have any non-FAL (since 6.0) installation anymore where I could test it.

Comment: Upgrading is out of my control unfortunately. But this is perfect. 1 Question: Is it better to make the menu `lib.menu` rather than `tt_content.menu.20.1.1` directly?

Comment: One last thing, how do I link the header? I tried `10.typolink.parameter.field = uid` with no results...

Comment: Using `lib.menu` has the advantage that I can use this snippet out of the box and add it anywhere else, e.g. with `page.20 < lib.menu`. I will answer the question in your new posting at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112688/typolink-content-in-menu