# Typolink content in menu?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am trying to make a menu that displays the page's first content element header and image and have them be links. But the typolink part doesn't seem to work for me:

```
lib.menu = HMENU
lib.menu {
  1 = TMENU
  1.NO {
    doNotLinkIt = 1
    wrapItemAndSub = <div>|</div>
    stdWrap.cObject = CONTENT
    stdWrap.cObject {
      table = tt_content
      select {
        pidInList.field = uid
      }
      renderObj = COA
      renderObj {

        10 = TEXT
        10.field = header
        10.typolink.parameter.field = uid
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where should the link go? To the page, or to the content element? If you want to go it to the page, you have to use `10.typolink.parameter.field = pid`, because the field is taken from the "current record", which is the content element you are rendering in a renderObj. In your case, the page ID is in the `pid` field of that content element.

Comment: @jost Yes, you are right! I was being dumb. Post this as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add give the full working example. Using `section.field = uid` you can link to the content element itself.

```
lib.menu = HMENU
lib.menu {
    1 = TMENU
    1.NO {
        doNotLinkIt = 1
        wrapItemAndSub = <div>|</div>
        stdWrap.cObject = CONTENT
        stdWrap.cObject {
            table = tt_content
            select {
                pidInList.field = uid
            }
            renderObj = COA
            renderObj {

                10 = TEXT
                10.field = header
                10.typolink {
                    parameter.field = pid
                    section.field = uid
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```